# Java jdbc timeout

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to my database with a singelton class in java. This is my current code:

```
public class Database {

public static Database instance;

private Connection connection;

private Database() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Log.debug("ok");
        this.connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://just.not.for.you:3006/database?connectTimeout=5000", "database", "secret");
        Log.debug("ok");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        Log.warn("Cloud not find jdbc driver class");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.warn("Cloud not connect to database: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}


public static synchronized Database getInstance() {
    if(Database.instance == null) {
        Database.instance = new Database();
    }
    return Database.instance;
}
```

In my main class i call `Database.getInstance()` but nothing happends. No error, no timeout message. It seems like an endless loop. I see the first debug message in line 10 but not the message in line 12.

What is the problem?

**Edit:** I can connect to the remote database with my local computer with mysql workbench

Comment: Have you tried setting system property `jdbc.drivers` to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or creating file `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` with driver's class name as its content?

Comment: Is the port number correct?  You're attempting to connect to port 3006 but port 3306 is the usual port for MySQL.

Comment: You are right. The port was the problem. Facepalm *_*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some problem in your code!

- Replace `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` with new driver`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`, because it is deprecated
- Checkout mysql server port, default port is 3306 not 3006

Comment: The newest driver still contains `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for backwards compatibility.